# React native windows image resizer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-windows

I've been trying to resize my images in a React Native Windows application I am developing. My goal is to render smaller images and save some processing and memory in the process.

However, I've hit an impasse. I can't find any Image Resizing libraries that support Windows (I've found a lot with Android and iOS support, though).

I've tried a lot of crazy things like converting it to bytes and using a for loop to copy the information to a new array, but I think there is no use trying that way.

I also tried with non-react-native-windows libraries like ImageResizer (no Windows support), to no avail.

I also don't have the technical knowledge to create a React-Native module of my own in C++, so I didn't consider that an option.

Any help that points me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using this library 'react-native-image-resizer'